# Image Animation stops automatically when the device orientation changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am new to iPhone development. I have an image view in my nib which I am successfully animating, making it to move from bottom to top using the following code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [self animateImage];    
}

-(void)animateImage{

    CGRect oldFrame=self.displayImg.frame;

     [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{

     CGRect newFrame=self.displayImg.frame;

      newFrame=CGRectOffset(newFrame, 0, -420);

      self.displayImg.frame=newFrame;

    }completion:^(BOOL finished){

        if(finished){

            self.displayImg.frame=oldFrame;

            [self animateImage];            
         }
    }];
}
```

My problem is when I change the device orientation  to Landscape the image animation stops and image disappears. Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, it doesn't buddy. I checked it myself. It works fine.
Work around, mistake be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I pasted my entire code . The only possibility , which I feel may be autosizing attribute of the image view

Comment: can you please send me the code . It will be really helpful for me.

Comment: Hi harshithgupta :).. Is it possible to send the code soon ? I am really in need now

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to send me the code . I will just check it and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: Your code is crashing with the reason:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setWindow:]

Comment: it worked fine. Thanks :) .. In the AppDelegate.m files , following 2 lines were missing.@synthesize window = _window; and @synthesize viewController = _viewController;

Comment: m using Xcode 4.4. that was the default template. so cant help the missig lines. Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine, the recursion is not interrupted and the animation continues. It means you are doing something yourself interrupting it if the recursion really stops or changing the view content/initial position so that you can't see it anymore while the animation is still working.

Comment: I have pasted my entire code . I feel I am not doing anything so that animation gets interrupted.

Comment: I am really not getting where I am doing wrong. It just a small code sample .

Comment: @user1626799 it is easy to check placing NSLog everywhere to monitor the running recursion and the image state, content and position. Also a small correction: use `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` with animated instead of YES.

Comment: Oh ok thanks . I corrected [super viewWillAppear:animated].; But not able to track the actual problem.

Comment: I got to know the problem now . When I change the device orientation,my animateImage not getting called .

Comment: But I really dont know why is this happening. Any suggestion,please? sorry for the lack of knowledge

Comment: @user1626799 you probably get the animation interrupted with another animation getting `finished` as `NO` and the recursion stopped.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16076/discussion-between-raj-and-a-live)